# Redirect uppercase to in lowercase in laravel

Tags: laravel

i want to redirect my url in Uppercase into lowercase In laravel

Example: https://www.divieducare.com/country/mbbs-in-Uzbekistan

want to 301 redirect in https://www.divieducare.com/country/mbbs-in-uzbekistan

Comment: Do you have setup route for lowercase?

Comment: no i am new my developer leave his job without doing these important changes so i want to know step by step guidance for redirect

Comment: This question doesn't have enough explanation. You should have written how you defined the routes, whether any part of the url is a dynamic parameter, and which controllers these routes are met with.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to process your URLs before redirecting

```
$url = 'https://www.divieducare.com/country/mbbs-in-Uzbekistan';
echo strtolower($url);
#redirect it anywhere
```